# Accessor methods and Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, attributes, getter, accessor

This is a question about how Java does reflection internally.

I have a abstract class say

```
SuperClass
```

and two chlid classes from SuperClass,

`ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2`.

`SuperClass` defines a accesor method `getValue()` although it dosen't define the attribute value.

`ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` override the method `getValue()` and both add an annotation `@MyAnnotation` to the method, `@MyAnnotation` is kept in runtime (It's the `OneToOne` annotation).

In my program I have an instance of `ChildClas1` and an instance of `ChildClass2`. I used reflection to obtain all methods from both objects.

As expected I got two `getValue()` methods in the resulting array, (one for the `SuperClass` and one for the `ChildClass`).

For the instances of `ChildClass1` the `getValue()` method that had `@MyAnnotation` was marked as a accessor (methodAccessor property != null) but for instances of `ChildClass2` the method marked as an accessor didn't have the annotation (was the `getValue()` method of the parent class).

I couldn't understand why, eventually I changed the order in which methods were declared in `ChildClass2` (There were more methods than just the accessors), namely I put all getters and setters at the begginging and `ChildClass2` was behaving as `ChildClass1`.

My question is, **how does Java qualify methods as accessors in reflection**, and further does the order in which methods are declared change the behavior of reflection?

Comment: After the first two sentences, I lost track, can you put a simple example together conveying what you want to achieve, your question is too long to grok...

Comment: Could you polish and re-format your question and post your actual code, please?

Answer (score 2):

> how does Java qualify methods as accessors in reflection,

It doesn't JavaBean is a convension which the Reflections library is not aware of.  If you use the Beans Introspector, this does make assumptions about getters and setters by names and number fo arguments.

> and further does the order in which methods are declared change the behavior of reflection?

The order the methods is defined tends to be the order they are retrieved e.g. getMethods() but you cannot rely on this behaviour.

Comment: I believe the order of methods returned by `getMethods()` has actually _changed_ between JDK versions.

Comment: and even if its true for recent versions of Hotspot/OpenJDK, it might not be true for other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Java reflection does not distinguish accessor methods from other - all are just methods. The order in which methods are declared does not matter.